# Will my plants get enough sun in this window?

Tags: sunlight, light

I'm planning on putting plants in this room next to the window but I'm not sure if they get enough sun here (for reference the plants I have are a few cacti, an echeveria, a house leek, a small bonsai and 2 jade plants). The picture is the window in the morning with the lights off when the sun is on the other side of the house[image]

Comment: So that window is facing west?

Comment: @MackM - That depends on  their location ?

Comment: Does it get afternoon sun ?

Comment: it gets the same ammount of sun in the picture all day until its dark though for about 3-4 hours in the early evening it gets a lot of full sun because thats where the sun would be facing

Comment: Four hours of sun is the minimum for your sun lovers, but the right side will get 30 minutes more. Cactus and succulents there; bonsai and jade on left.

Comment: @RohitGupta Yes, only true on Earth :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard for me to judge how 'much' light an area is getting with just your eye, and even harder through a photograph.  I'm going by you saying it is on the opposite side of the house as sunrise and gets direct light in the evening, so that's a West facing window that gets 3-4 hours of direct light a day and indirect light the rest of the day.

For most of the plants you listed, I think that's on the low side but maybe OK. The cacti, echeveria, and jade plants will want sunlight and grow 'leggy' if they aren't getting what they need.  Maybe you can try this window and watch for leggy plants as a sign to move them to brighter windows?

[image: Leggy Plant]

I don't have any experience with house leeks or bonsai/Chinese Elm, but I am reading online that they may be OK with the partial sunlight in that window.   Good luck with your plants!